# How can I use Html::getUniqueID?

Tags: theming

My Drupal entity (block, node, paragraph, comment, whathaveyou)  needs an HTML ID generated in various rendered view modes (full node, teaser, etc).

I could manually generate one using the entity `type_or_bundle_name` + `entity_id`, but if the entity appears more than once on a page a few things happen:

- accessibility testing tools report failures.
- many browsers complain about it in the JS console
- all because, technically, this goes against HTML spec (ids must be unique on the page).

In the vast majority of cases, *if you're generating an ID in Twig you really need to be guaranteeing uniqueness*.

It is hard to believe Drupal doesn't support this out of the box.

The Drupal Twig [`clean_id`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates#clean_id) filter calls [`HTML::getId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetId/8.7.x), which does nothing more than strip invalid characters but doesnt ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I agree -- it's utterly bizarre that a Twig filter for `getUniqueId()` isn't included.  It looks like someone stepped up to remedy this, though: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3115445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `clean_id` filter isn't providing a unique ID, but removing from the string used as HTML ID the characters that aren't allowed. Basing on [6.2 SGML basic types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) HTML IDs can only contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and colons.

[`Html::getUniqueId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetUniqueId/8.9.x) itself uses `Html::getId()`.

```php
// If this is an Ajax request, then content returned by this page request
// will be merged with content already on the base page. The HTML IDs must
// be unique for the fully merged content. Therefore use unique IDs.
if (static::$isAjax) {
  return static::getId($id) . '--' . Crypt::randomBytesBase64(8);
}

// @todo Remove all that code once we switch over to random IDs only,
// see https://www.drupal.org/node/1090592.
if (!isset(static::$seenIdsInit)) {
  static::$seenIdsInit = [];
}
if (!isset(static::$seenIds)) {
  static::$seenIds = static::$seenIdsInit;
}
$id = static::getId($id);
```

[The documentation page for `Html::getId()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AgetId/8.9.x) says it should be used only when the ID doesn't need to be unique.

For the cases where the ID needs to be unique, Drupal core modules set a variable passed to the template file, which is what's done in [`template_preprocess_pager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21pager.inc/function/template_preprocess_pager/8.9.x), [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.9.x), or [`template_preprocess_views_view_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_table/8.9.x), for example.

```php
variables['heading_id'] = Html::getUniqueId('pagination-heading');
```

```php
// Create a valid HTML ID and make sure it is unique.
if (!empty($variables['elements']['#id'])) {
  $variables['attributes']['id'] = Html::getUniqueId('block-' . $variables['elements']['#id']);
}
```

```php
// Improves accessibility of complex tables.
$variables['header'][$field]['attributes']['id'] = Html::getUniqueId('view-' . $field . '-table-column');
```

Since Drupal core doesn't have a Twig filter that returns a unique ID, that is the only way to obtain one: Set a variable in a preprocess function used for the template file with the value returned from `Html::getUniqueId()`, and use that variable where the template file needs a unique ID.